# How to create manage fixed background with CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a background-effect that looks like this: http://goo.gl/ZVIdvp using PURE CSS only.

I also want to know how can I make it responsive as well.

So far here's what I have on my HTML:

```
    <header class="header">
        <h1>Fixed Background Effect</h1>
    </header>

    <section class="background-fixed img-1">
        <div class="main-content">
            <h2>Title here</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem dolor beatae, laudantium eos fugiat, deserunt delectus quibusdam quae placeat, tempora ea? Nulla ducimus, magnam sunt repellendus modi, ad ipsam est.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="background-fixed img-2">
        <div class="main-content light-background">
            <h2>Title here</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem dolor beatae, laudantium eos fugiat, deserunt delectus quibusdam quae placeat, tempora ea? Nulla ducimus, magnam sunt repellendus modi, ad ipsam est.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="background-fixed img-3">
        <div class="main-content">
            <h2>Title here</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem dolor beatae, laudantium eos fugiat, deserunt delectus quibusdam quae placeat, tempora ea? Nulla ducimus, magnam sunt repellendus modi, ad ipsam est.</p>
        </div>
    </section>

    <section class="background-fixed img-4" data-type="slider-item">
        <div class="main-content">
            <h2>Title here</h2>
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem dolor beatae, laudantium eos fugiat, deserunt delectus quibusdam quae placeat, tempora ea? Nulla ducimus, magnam sunt repellendus modi, ad ipsam est.</p>
        </div>
    </section>


<footer>
    <p>&copy; Copyright 2015 </p>
</footer>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
*, *::after, *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #0f594d;
  background-color: #f2e6cd;
}

a {
  color: #93a748;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main Components 

-------------------------------- */
.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #34495e;
  z-index: 1;
}
.header h1 {
  width: 90%;
  color: #f2e6cd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-header h1 {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}

.background-fixed {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3em 5% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.background-fixed h2, .background-fixed p {
  color: #f2e6cd;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.background-fixed h2 {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.background-fixedp {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
}
.background-fixed .light-background h2, .background-fixed .light-background p {
  color: #0f594d;
}
.background-fixed .main-content::after {
  /* phone image on small devices */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 60% 0;
  margin: 2em auto 0;
}
.background-fixed.img-1 {
  background-color: #bf5138;
}


.background-fixed.img-2 {
  background-color: #f2e6cd;
}

.background-fixed.img-3 {
  background-color: #0f594d;
}


.background-fixed.img-4 {
  background-color: #db9537;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .background-fixed {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .background-fixed h2 {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
  .background-fixed p {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
  }

  .background-fixed.img-1 {
    background-image: url("http://halloweenmaternitycostumes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/img-1.jpg");
  }
  .background-fixed.img-2 {
    background-image: url("http://halloweenmaternitycostumes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/img-2.jpg");
  }
  .background-fixed.img-3 {
    background-image: url("http://halloweenmaternitycostumes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/img-3.jpg");
  }
  .background-fixed.img-4 {
    background-image: url("http://halloweenmaternitycostumes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/img-4.jpg");
  }
}


footer {
  background: #dadada;
  padding: 15px 0;

}

footer p{
  color: #000;
  text-align:center;
}
```

Any idea how to do it using CSS? Here's my JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/v7a58odd/1/

Comment: I guess without jQuery it cannot be done.

Comment: @stanze: How can we do that then? How can I apply jQuery?

Comment: Please don't vandalise your posts.

Answer (score 6):

Everything is fine in your code, you only missed one style

```
 .background-fixed{
         background-attachment:fixed;
    }
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/0f89ptc3/1/)

Comment: Where are the images? I can't see them. Also it won't work as we are crossing images per section check your codes.

Comment: Yeah it won't just work. Also where are the images? Each section will cross each other.

Comment: Expand results window to see images or use full screen jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0f89ptc3/1/embedded/result/ 
In your code if screen width is less than 768px images are not shown

Comment: How to make it responsive then? also why is there a space for every section and a big space on the footer. See image: http://prntscr.com/7ka5vo Another thing the text on the side of the images wont scroll properly and not aligned.

Comment: It's not responsive @Gvidas also there are spaces and won't just work on the text. It must flexible.

Comment: Not all necessary css was copied in your jsFiddle, here is full copied version: https://jsfiddle.net/v8dxee30/1/, note that in this fiddle `background-attachemnt: fixed;` only applies on width 1048px and more

Comment: where did you get this class? cd-fixed-background and this one? data-type="slider-item"

Answer (score 2):

```css
/* -------------------------------- 

Primary style

-------------------------------- */
*, *::after, *::before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
  font-size: 62.5%;
}

body {
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-family: "Open Sans", sans-serif;
  color: #0f594d;
  background-color: #f2e6cd;
}

a {
  color: #93a748;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* -------------------------------- 

Main Components 

-------------------------------- */
.header {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #34495e;
  z-index: 1;
}
.header h1 {
  width: 90%;
  color: #f2e6cd;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.2rem;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  bottom: auto;
  right: auto;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -moz-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -ms-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  -o-transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
  transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .cd-header h1 {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    font-weight: 300;
  }
}

.background-fixed {
  position: relative;
  padding: 3em 5% 0;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}
.background-fixed h2, .background-fixed p {
  color: #f2e6cd;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
.background-fixed h2 {
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
.background-fixedp {
  line-height: 1.6;
  font-family: "Merriweather", serif;
}
.background-fixed .light-background h2, .background-fixed .light-background p {
  color: #0f594d;
}
.background-fixed .main-content::after {
  /* phone image on small devices */
  content: '';
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 60% 0;
  margin: 2em auto 0;
}
.background-fixed.img-1 {
  background-color: #bf5138;
}


.background-fixed.img-2 {
  background-color: #f2e6cd;
}

.background-fixed.img-3 {
  background-color: #0f594d;
}


.background-fixed.img-4 {
  background-color: #db9537;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
  .background-fixed {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
  .background-fixed h2 {
    font-size: 3.6rem;
    font-weight: 300;
        margin:0;
  }
  .background-fixed p {
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    line-height: 1.8;
  }
  
  .background-fixed.img-1 {
    background-image: url("http://halloweenmaternitycostumes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/img-1.jpg");
        background-attachment:fixed;
  }
  .background-fixed.img-2 {
    background-image: url("http://halloweenmaternitycostumes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/img-2.jpg");
        background-attachment:fixed;
  }
  .background-fixed.img-3 {
    background-image: url("http://halloweenmaternitycostumes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/img-3.jpg");
        background-attachment:fixed;
  }
  .background-fixed.img-4 {
    background-image: url("http://halloweenmaternitycostumes.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/06/img-4.jpg");
        background-attachment:fixed;
  }
}


footer {
  background: #dadada;
  padding: 15px 0;

}

footer p{
  color: #000;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
 <header class="header">
  <h1>Fixed Background Effect</h1>
 </header>
 
 <section class="background-fixed img-1">
  <div class="main-content">
   <h2>Title here</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem dolor beatae, laudantium eos fugiat, deserunt delectus quibusdam quae placeat, tempora ea? Nulla ducimus, magnam sunt repellendus modi, ad ipsam est.</p>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section class="background-fixed img-2">
  <div class="main-content light-background">
   <h2>Title here</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem dolor beatae, laudantium eos fugiat, deserunt delectus quibusdam quae placeat, tempora ea? Nulla ducimus, magnam sunt repellendus modi, ad ipsam est.</p>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section class="background-fixed img-3">
  <div class="main-content">
   <h2>Title here</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem dolor beatae, laudantium eos fugiat, deserunt delectus quibusdam quae placeat, tempora ea? Nulla ducimus, magnam sunt repellendus modi, ad ipsam est.</p>
  </div>
 </section>

 <section class="background-fixed img-4" data-type="slider-item">
  <div class="main-content">
   <h2>Title here</h2>
   <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Autem dolor beatae, laudantium eos fugiat, deserunt delectus quibusdam quae placeat, tempora ea? Nulla ducimus, magnam sunt repellendus modi, ad ipsam est.</p>
  </div>
 </section>


<footer>
 <p>&copy; Copyright 2015 </p>
</footer>
```

Try This.